# Conversion from dictionary to list preserving elements

Tags: python

I've a problem with conversion from this:

```
Counter({('pintor', 'NCMS000'): 1, ('ser', 'VSIS3S0'): 1, ('muralista', 'AQ0CS0'): 1, ('diego_rivera', 'NP00000'): 1, ('frida_kahlo', 'NP00000'): 1, ('caso', 'NCMS000'): 1})
```

That is obtained from this code:

```
res = collections.Counter(map(tuple, listaPalabras)) return res
```

But what I need is a list in this form:

```
[['pintor', 'NCMS000', 1], ['ser', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['muralista', 'AQ0CS0', 1], ['diego_rivera', 'NP00000', 1], ['frida_kahlo', 'NP00000', 1], ('caso', 'NCMS000', 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the counter with a list comprehension:

```
[list(k) + [v] for k, v in res.iteritems()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> res = Counter({('pintor', 'NCMS000'): 1, ('ser', 'VSIS3S0'): 1, ('muralista', 'AQ0CS0'): 1, ('diego_rivera', 'NP00000'): 1, ('frida_kahlo', 'NP00000'): 1, ('caso', 'NCMS000'): 1})
>>> [list(k) + [v] for k, v in res.iteritems()]
[['pintor', 'NCMS000', 1], ['ser', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['diego_rivera', 'NP00000', 1], ['frida_kahlo', 'NP00000', 1], ['muralista', 'AQ0CS0', 1], ['caso', 'NCMS000', 1]]
```

If you wanted your values to be listed in sorted order, use `.most_common()` instead of `.iteritems()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter({('pintor', 'NCMS000'): 1, ('ser', 'VSIS3S0'): 1, ('muralista', 'AQ0CS0'): 1, ('diego_rivera', 'NP00000'): 1, ('frida_kahlo', 'NP00000'): 1, ('caso', 'NCMS000'): 1})
>>> [[key[0], key[1], value] for key, value in c.iteritems()]
[['pintor', 'NCMS000', 1], ['ser', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['diego_rivera', 'NP00000', 1], ['frida_kahlo', 'NP00000', 1], ['muralista', 'AQ0CS0', 1], ['caso', 'NCMS000', 1]]
```

The code uses `list comprehension` to construct a list of lists by looping over `Counter` items (both keys and values) using `iteritems()`. Since each key in your case is a tuple of length 2 - it gets each part of the tuple by index: `key[0]`, `key[1]`.

Comment: Can you perhaps add some words to explain to the code or your approach to the OP?

Comment: Thanks to all your answers, one more thing: I need to substract the last element and buid a vector like [1,1,1,...]. I,ve this function:######def vectores(lista):
    r=[]
    for e in lista:
        r.append(e[1])
        return r######## and is giving me [1]. what can I do?

Comment: Yup, make this a separate question please.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> data = Counter({('pintor', 'NCMS000'): 1, ('ser', 'VSIS3S0'): 1, ('muralista', 'AQ0CS0'): 1, ('diego_rivera', 'NP00000'): 1, ('frida_kahlo', 'NP00000'): 1, ('caso', 'NCMS000'): 1})
>>> [[k[0], k[1], v] for k, v in data.items()]
[['pintor', 'NCMS000', 1], ['ser', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['diego_rivera', 'NP00000', 1], ['frida_kahlo', 'NP00000', 1], ['muralista', 'AQ0CS0', 1], ['caso', 'NCMS000', 1]]
```

Or an alternative using tuple unpacking:

```
>>> [[a, b, v] for (a, b), v in data.items()]
[['pintor', 'NCMS000', 1], ['ser', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['diego_rivera', 'NP00000', 1], ['frida_kahlo', 'NP00000', 1], ['muralista', 'AQ0CS0', 1], ['caso', 'NCMS000', 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
[[i, j, k] for ((i, j), k) in res.items()]
```